# How to change the color of a seat ( image button ) when it is selected & when it is de-selected it has to regain its original state(white or no color)

Tags: asp.net

Hi respected developers,
I am trying to develop a sample movie ticket booking application.When a seat (image button) is selected, the color has to change and when it is de-selected the color has to regain its normal position i.e.,white or no color.Can anybody take me to the right path.When seat image is selected.
But it shows turning of seat into blue up to 1 second and getting back to its normal position.

imagebuttonSeat1.Backcolor=System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to first set one condition in which first check for seat is booked or not if seat is not booked then put that statement in the true condition same for seat is not booked.

suppose your seat is booked.

```
if(seatBooked==1){
      imagebuttonSeat1.Backcolor=System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
}
else{
      imagebuttonSeat1.Backcolor=System.Drawing.Color.White;
}
```

I think it will work just Try it.

Regards,
Dilip SUtariya

Comment: How can we set if condition using my imagebutton name?

Comment: You can give condition like if(imageButton1.backcolor==color.White) if it true then set your color to button.

Comment: Hi Sutariya, I got the blue color.But is it possible to be in blue color until imagebutton is de-selected?